# Silverlight in a Cocoa WebView in sandboxed app mode

Tags: silverlight, cocoa, webview, sandbox, entitlements

The problem is quite simple, I have a WebView that may be used to browse some page that may contain a silverlight app.

Everything works well in non sandboxed mode.

In sandboxed mode, all the webkit plugins work, except Silverlight: no exception thrown, nothing in the sandboxd logs, just an empty silverlight app placeholder in the page.

I was wondering if anyone stumbled upon the same issue and found a way to make it work :)

Update: I added the following key/value to my entitlements file but it did not help

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-lookup.global-name</key>
<array>
    <string>com.apple.WebKit.PluginAgent</string>
</array>
```

Update 2: silverlight version 5.1.10411.0, Mac OSX: 10.8 (12A269)

Answer (score 0):

I have it working on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4 (11E53), 
using:

```
<key>com.apple.security.temporary-exception.mach-lookup.global-name</key>
<array>
    <string>com.apple.WebKit.PluginAgent</string>
</array>
```

In the .entitlements file. Tested both Silverlight, and flash plugins in the WebView.

Comment: unfortunately this is not enough to make it work on my mountain lion :(. I'll try to check with other OSX 10.8 installs, and older silverlight plugin versions.